# AC vs DC and ELF - extremely low frequency

Tags: power, batteries, current, dc, ac

given :

> How do static fields differ from time-varying fields ? A static field does not vary over time. A direct current (DC) is an electric current flowing in one direction only. In any battery-powered appliance the current flows from the battery to the appliance and then back to the battery. It will create a static magnetic field. .... In contrast, time-varying electromagnetic fields are produced by alternating currents (AC)

are thus extremely low frequency -ELF - fields a property of AC current only and not of DC?, that way when an electrical appliance such as a phone/tablet/laptop runs on battery only  does not emmit ELF, but on the other hand when plugged into a socket becomes subject to AC, thus emmiting ELF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define ELF. The ITU and IEEE designation is electromagnetic radiation at frequencies from >0.3Hz to 300Hz. However the [World Health Organization's](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/facts/fs322/en/) extremely low frequency category goes down to *zero*, so turning your phone off at night could be causing it to produce ELF at 11.6µHz.

If ELF is from >0.3Hz to 300Hz, then a phone charger that draws pulses of current at 301Hz is not producing ELF, but one which charges with a 'DC' current interrupted every 2.99 seconds *is* (that the current is always flowing in the same direction is irrelevant - the *variation* is still AC).

> A static field does not vary over time

A truly static field is impossible - unless it has *always* existed. In practice we call a field 'static' if it doesn't vary significantly over the length of time we are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is incorrect on this bit: -

> In any battery-powered appliance the current flows from the battery to
>   the appliance and then back to the battery. It will create a static
>   magnetic field.

The above is wrong - most battery powered pieces of equipment consume a static current (basically the average current taken) and an alternating current superimposed on the static current. The alternating current produces alternating magnetic fields which can be detected.

An exception to this is a battery connected to a passive component like a resistor. In this case the current might decrease very slowly over time (due to battery exhausting itself) but the slowness of the current change (in the order of milli amps per hour) will not generate a field that is easily detectable other than by using a gauss/flux meter (they are also used to measure the earth's largely static magnetic field.